# Which delete query is better with prepare or delete

Tags: customization

Just wondering which of the two delete queries would be the preffered method

```
$qdel = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("DELETE FROM $shopping_meta_table WHERE meta_shopping_key = '%s' AND wp_user_id = %d", 'product-2', $id));
```

or

```
$qdel = $wpdb->delete($shopping_meta_table,array('meta_shopping_key' => 'product-2', 'wp_user_id'=>$id));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your **reputation** , It seems that you know about the wordpress very well.

Use of `prepare` method in query is to make sure we're not dealing with an illegal operation or any illegal characters.So I recommend you to delete with the `prepare` method.

Other than that, you might be aware of **SQL INJECTION**. Before release of **wordpress 2.5**, there was `$wpdb->escape()` to prevent SQL Injection whose work was to prevent  SQL injection attacks and keeping the bad dudes out. Since WordPress 2.5 a new $wpdb function has been included called ‘prepare’, whose work is to prevent SQL escapes.

So All data in SQL queries must be SQL-escaped before the SQL query is executed to prevent against SQL injection attacks. The `prepare` method performs this functionality for WordPress, which supports both a sprintf()-like and vsprintf()-like syntax.

[Read more](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation#Database) about **SQL escaping**.

[Prepare Function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).